# Remove Edit Button from moreNavigationController dont work

Tags: objective-c

i get some problem by removing the Edit Button from the `moreNavigationController`.

I cant find the mistake, it must be a simple one.

I create some `TabBarViewController` connect it in the IB with my `TabBarViewController`.

Here is the Code:

**TabBarViewController.h**:

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TabBarViewController : UITabBarController <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>


@end
```

**TabBarViewController.m**:

```
#import "TabBarViewController.h"

@interface TabBarViewController ()

@end

@implementation TabBarViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

     self.delegate = self;

   [self.moreNavigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];
    [self.moreNavigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar.bg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [self.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.topItem setRightBarButtonItem:nil];   

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

The Edit Button is stil there :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set the navigationController delegate to your tabBarController. Add the following line in your viewDidLoad method of your `TabBarViewController` class

```
self.moreNavigationController.delegate = self;
```

use the delegate method of UINavigationController `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:` to hide the barButtonItem

**Use the following code**

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
  willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItem = Nil;
}
```

This should work, it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

There is a more pretty solution:

```
tabBarController.customizableViewControllers = [];
```

Comment: Which version of iOS did you test this on? I tried and it does not work on 10.2

Answer (score 0):

Prasad Devadiga Thanks man!
In my TabBarViewController.m

```
#import "TabBarViewController.h"

@interface TabBarViewController ()

@end

@implementation TabBarViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.moreNavigationController.delegate = self;
    navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:YES;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
      willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                    animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItem = Nil;
}

@end
```

In my TabBarViewController.h
I insert this codes

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TabBarViewController : UITabBarController <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>

@end
```

This is working on IOS7

Answer (score 0):

After reading all of the above and converting it to Swift 3 I noticed that when one of the view controllers which was shown after selecting the More... tab was a navigationcontroller and had a rightBarButton item, that item was removed as well! Since that is not desired, I came up with the following solution:

```
//
//  CustomizedTabBarController.swift
//

import UIKit

class CustomizedTabBarController: UITabBarController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    var root : UIViewController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        root = self.moreNavigationController.topViewController

        // Make sure the icons have the proper tint color
        if let view = root?.view {
            view.tintColor = UIColor.green
        }

        self.moreNavigationController.delegate = self

    }

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        // Only hide the rightBarButtonItem when this is the morenavigationcontroller
        if( viewController == root ){
            navigationController.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem = nil
        }
    }
}
```

As an extra I also force the icons shown in the moreNavigationController to be green instead of the standard blue tintcolor since I was using green icons on the tabbar as well.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
    tabBarController.customizableViewControllers?.removeAll()
}
```